# how to link libs (.so y .a) properly with cmake

Tags: c++, linux, g++, cmake

ok, let say I have build some libs called `libImmortal.a` and `libUglyFace.so`. The first one is in `~/LakeOfBlood/lib`, the second is installed trough `make install` in `/usr/lib`. In bonus I do a `ldconfig`

now in `~/LakeOfBlood` I want to edit `CMakeList.txt`. I add libs :

```
project (LOB)
.
.
.
# (the binary will be built in ~/LakeOfBlood)
link_directories(${LOB_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
.
.
.
target_link_libraries(LakeOfBlood UglyFace Immortal)
```

but when I compil `ld` can't find `Immortal`

I can still link by changing :

```
target_link_libraries(LakeOfBlood UglyFace Immortal)
```

by

```
target_link_libraries(LakeOfBlood UglyFace /home/OftheBeast/LakeOfBlood/Immortal.a)
```

then `ld` works.

...BUTT, yes there is a f* * * * * * "but"...

when I start LakeOfBlood, I got :

`./LakeOfBlood: error while loading shared libraries: libUglyFace.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

The two libs aren't mine, they come with a sample called `OccultGod`. If I do `ldd OccultGod` I got :

`libUglyFace.so => /home/OfTheBeast/LakeOfBlood/lib/libUglyFace.so (0x0000666)`

so now,

1. how can I say to `OccultGod` to use `/usr/lib/libUglyFace.so` instead of the one above ? (trough his own `CMakeList.txt`)
2. how can I fix my `CMakeList.txt` for `libImmortal.a`
3. could you explain to me why `LakeOfBlood` can't see `/usr/lib/libUglyFace.so`. I mean `/usr/lib` is the standard path right? then I thought every libs there, will be automatically found by any binary...

Answer (score 0):

1. Use path instead of target name: `target_link_libraries(OccultGod /usr/lib/libUglyFace.so)`
2. I didn't get what's the problem here, but you shouldn't you make `T` in `/home/OftheBeast` capital?
3. I suppose because it's rpath'ed into executable. Either `make install` your project or do not use target name in `target_link_libraries()`.